# disable back-button only in ONE method

Tags: android, methods, back

I want to disable the back-button in my application. But ONLY when this method is active:

```
public void winCross() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.winnercross);
    dialog.show();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems like you don't want the user to be able to go back from the dialog? if that's the case just set : dialog.setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

This will make the back button have no effect on the dialog, rather than disabling the back button for only that method (which is fiddly).

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed() in the dialog and do nothing in there.